# Get the_field of Advanced Custom Fields in a custom query

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom query to display content of a certain template:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $pages = get_pages(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => 'sale.php'
    ));
    foreach($pages as $page){
        echo '<div class="content_'. $i .'">' . apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content ) . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="title_' . $i . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title) . '</div>';
        echo '<p>' . the_field('sale_images_url') . '</p>';
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

which works fine for `the_content()` and `the_title()` so far. Want I also wanna do is, to display the value of an [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/) named `sale_images_url`.

But it displays nothing. Do I have to handle this different?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need to pass the page ID to `the_field` and for that matter `get_post_meta` as well

You can try the following

```
the_field( 'sale_images_url', $page->ID );
```

Comment: `the_field` won't work within an echo statement, and `get_post_meta` isn't safe for outputting ACF fields because different fields have different formatting options which change their output.

Comment: @Milo OK, did not know about the `get_post_meta` part. On `the_field`, my answer is just an example of how to pass the page ID. And I did not include `echo` as anything without an `get_` prefix are usually (but not always) echo'd and therefor no need to `echo` it manually

Comment: in the context of OP's code, `the_field` will produce incorrect results.

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks again for your help! Your first snippet worked!

Comment: Glad it helped. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can print custom filed value with `get_field` function in ACF you can do this.

Inside the loop.

```
<?php echo get_field( 'sale_images_url' ); ?>
```

Outside the loop.

```
<?php echo get_field( 'sale_images_url', $page->ID ); ?>
```

Removed `get_post_meta` example because as pointed out by @Milo it will not produce correct result. Thanks.

Comment: but this is the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Which uses `the_field()` as its own function. Please see the link in OP.

Comment: Okay I have updated the answer. But `get_post_meta` will also work.

Comment: you can't always use `get_post_meta` as a replacement for `get_field`, because different ACF fields have different formatting options which change their output.

Comment: I think it's same because output for both can be string or array for different ACF fields. And in both cases, we will need to use same method to output required data. Isn't it?

Comment: an example- the taxonomy field stores a term's ID, but it might output either the ID or a term object, depending on the return value setting for that field, so in some cases the two functions will produce different output.

Comment: Hmm, I noticed that on some of examples. Thanks for pointing out.